# SymPy: Union of symbolic Interval

Tags: union, intervals, sympy, symbolic-math

I have two Sympy interval `(Interval(1, m), Interval(1, m+1))` where `m>=1`.
I want to make the Union of those 2 intervals. The result should be `[1,m+1]`

Unfortunately I was not able to pass to Sympy the constraint on `m`.

Where is my actual code with the 'too mush general' answer:

```
m = symbols('m', integer=True)
Union(Interval(1, m), Interval(1, m+1))
>> [1, m] U [1, m + 1]
```

I tried to use the `reduce` function without any success...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like this simplification isn't implemented. You should open an issue in the SymPy [issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new) about it.

Comment: @asmeurer I will, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can get the desired output by creating a new interval12 like so:

```
m=Symbol('m',positive=True)
interval1 = Interval(0,m)
interval2 = Interval(0,m+4)
union12 = interval1.union(interval2)
interval12 = Interval(union12.inf,union12.sup)
print interval1, interval2, interval12
```

output:

```
[0, m] [0, m + 4] [0, m + 4]
```